# PHP vs python, performance issue in php

Tags: php, python, performance, prime-factoring

There is an algorithm for *prime factorization* in `python`. It runs in about 10 milliseconds for a big integer. I rewrote it for `php`. Also For very big integers I used `bc` and `gmp` functions in php. The result is **very slow** and takes about 4 seconds for the same input!

Here is my code:

(**NOTE:** the functions into the main function are tested separately and they are very fast)

```
public function primefactors($n, $sort = false) {


    $smallprimes = $this->primesbelow(10000);
    $factors = [];

    // NOTE: bc or gmp functions is used for big numbers calculations
    $limit = bcadd( bcsqrt($n) , 1);
    foreach ($smallprimes as $checker) {
        if ($checker > $limit) {
            break;
        }
        // while (gmp_mod($n, $checker) == 0) {
        // while ($n%$checker == 0) {
        while ( bcmod($n, $checker) == 0 ) {
            array_push($factors, $checker);
            // $n = (int)($n/$checker);
            $n = bcdiv($n, $checker);
            // $limit = (int)(bcpow($n, 0.5)) + 1;
            $limit = bcadd( bcsqrt($n) , 1);
            if ($checker > $limit) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($n < 2) {
        return $factors;
    }

    while ($n > 1) {
        if ($this->isprime($n)) {
            array_push($factors, $n);
            // var_dump($factors);
            break;
        }
        $factor  = $this->pollard_brent($n);
        $factors = array_merge($factors, $this->primefactors($factor)); 
        $n = (int)($n/$factor);
    }
    if ($sort) {
        sort($factors);
    }

    return $factors;

}
```

Is there any performance issue in my code?? Or `php` itself has performance issue? Why python is so fast? (About 40 times faster)

**Edit:** Here is the python code:

```
smallprimes = primesbelow(10000) # might seem low, but 1000*1000 = 1000000, so this will fully factor every composite < 1000000
def primefactors(n, sort=False):
    factors = []

    limit = int(n ** .5) + 1
    for checker in smallprimes:
        if checker > limit: break
        while n % checker == 0:
            factors.append(checker)
            n //= checker
            limit = int(n ** .5) + 1
            if checker > limit: break

    if n < 2: return factors

    while n > 1:
        if isprime(n):
            factors.append(n)
            break
        factor = pollard_brent(n) # trial division did not fully factor, switch to pollard-brent
        factors.extend(primefactors(factor)) # recurse to factor the not necessarily prime factor returned by pollard-brent
        n //= factor

    if sort: factors.sort()

    return factors
```

Comment: without the corresponding Python code how can we compare your "translation"?

Comment: Ok, let me provide python code. Thanks.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Please check edit part.

Comment: @vahidnajafi You might be using a very old PHP version. Here's a legit benchmark from Debian between PHP and Python https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/php.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this benchmarks https://blog.famzah.net/2016/02/09/cpp-vs-python-vs-perl-vs-php-performance-benchmark-2016/

You are asking why a turttle is slower than a horse doing the same circuit.

Comment: Thanks. But this article claims that `php7` is the fastest. but in my case, it's opposite. And your example about hourse and turttle is not true, because in computer sience the algorithm is very important. Language should not make this much difference. Maybe I have a performance implemented issue.

Comment: What about Compiled languages vs Interpreted Languages? There is the difference.